# Using stored variables with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string

How to use a stored string which contains a variable?

Example:

I have to gather error notifications strings from the database. These notifications are divided into two types. Regular (common, frequent) strings and targeted (specifically intended) strings.

Let's assume that I have already fetched regular strings and the array was created.

```
print_r ( $reg_errs );
Array ( [unexp_err] => Array (
  [eng] => An unexpected error has become.
) )
```

Then I have fetched the array of targeted errors

```
print_r ( $targ_errs );
Array ( [incorr_cfg_langs] => Array (
  [eng] => $reg_errs['unexp_err']['eng'] . ' Incorrect configuration settings of language versions.'
) )
```

.

```
echo $targ_errs['incorr_cfg_langs']['eng'];
```

The result will be:

*$reg_errs['unexp_err']['eng'] . ' Incorrect configuration settings of language versions.'*

The requested result is:

*An unexpected error has become. Incorrect configuration settings of language versions.*

Is there a way to reach my goal? Thank you for any advice ☺

EDIT:

```
if ( $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare ( "..." ) ) {
    $stmt -> execute ();
    $res = $stmt -> get_result ();
    if ( mysqli_num_rows ( $res ) != NULL ) {
        while ( $row = $res -> fetch_assoc () ) {
            $error = str_replace ( ' ', '', $row['error_assoc_id'] );
            $error_chars_no = mb_strlen ( $error );
            $lang_iso = str_replace ( ' ', '', $row['lang_iso'] );
            $lang_iso_chars_no = mb_strlen ( $lang_iso );
            $value = trim ( $row['value'] );
            $value_chars_no = mb_strlen ( $value );
            if ( ( $error_chars_no >= 3 ) && ( $lang_iso_chars_no == 3 ) && ( $value_chars_no >=3 ) ) {
                $targ_errs[$error][$lang_iso] = $value;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

}

Comment: So you are saying that `$reg_errs['unexp_err']['eng'] . ' Incorrect configuration settings of language versions.'` is becoming as single string (`"$reg_errs['unexp_err']['eng'] . ' Incorrect configuration settings of language versions.'"`) instead of variable and string concatenation? Are you hiding some code from us?

Comment: "An expected error has become" is just the string inside `$reg_errs['unexp_err']['eng']`.

Comment: I have edited echo, there was ['unexp_err'] key and now it is correct. Yes, the result is like you see it in my question and I am not hiding any relevant code.

Comment: Could you please post code, instead of `print_r` output?

Comment: @AwesomeGuy What code exactly?

Comment: The code that generates the output you want, but doesn't. Then I can troubleshoot a lot easier.

Comment: @AwesomeGuy It is 150 rows code..

Comment: Post to pastebin.com. You are simply not showing enough of your problem.

Comment: Nevermind, someone has got it!

Comment: You are building $targ_errs array incorrectly so no use just posting output.

Comment: This is so rude, impolite and snobby community... I have no reason to stay here.

Answer (score 2):

What about this,

```
$sp_err = array ( 'unexp_err' => array (
  'eng' => 'An unexpected error has become.'
) );



$reg_err = array ( 'incorr_cfg_langs' => array (
  'eng' => $sp_err['unexp_err']['eng'] . ' Incorrect configuration settings of language versions.'
) );

echo $reg_err['incorr_cfg_langs']['eng'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it looks like the same what I have now.

Comment: This should really work, great PHP, and should work as intended.